# How to set all tabbar are not active in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my app I have taken tabbar as a child view in my Homeviewcontroller screen using following code:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.title = @"Home";

    UIViewController* controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,60, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-200);
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

but my problem is, it shows the first tab active, and show the first tab content on Homeviewcontrller screen, but i don't want to any tab active on Homeviewcontrller , i only want to show tabbar on Homeviewcontrller. and when i click any tab it will show appropriate screen.

Is there any solution on that in objective-C?

Comment: self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.enabled = NO;   Write this all tab items... viewController

Comment: Thanks, but i don't to enableor disable any button , on homescreen i want to show only tabbar, and homescreen is not associated with any tab button

Comment: use background image having tabbar :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not how `UITabBarController` works. There must always be one active tab, and corresponding view controller displayed.

You could add your `HomeViewController` to the `UITabBarController` and show its tab when app starts. Then you can switch between all the tabs including home.

Comment: Thanks, but as per my apps requirement I want this type of architecture, is there any way to do that?

Comment: I suppose you can subclass `UITabBarController` and implement it / write your own container. AFAIK there is no other solution

Comment: As I said, this is non standard behavior, and I don't know any library that enables you to do that, so custom - non trivial - solution needs to be made. I wouldn't expect anyone to create it for you.